# How can I match all instances of the first letter?

Tags: regex

For example, for this string I want to match all `A` and `a`:

"**A**ll the **a**pples m**a**ke good c**a**ke."

Here's what I did: `/(.)[^.]*\1*/ig`

I started by getting the first character in the group, which can be any character: `(.)` Then I added `[^.]*` because I don't want to match any other character that isn't the first one. Finally I added `\1*` because I wanted to match the first character again. All other similar variations that I've tried don't seem to work.

Comment: `[^.]*` has no back-reference - it's just saying "not wildcard" which will never match anything.  This really seems like something that would be better suited to simple string operations unless you've got a really solid reason to use regex.

Comment: Try `\b[^\WAa]*([Aa])[^\WAa]*\b` This regex can be constructed by first matching `\b[a-zA-Z]` then making the above regex with what that letter is. Then use that regex for all your matches.

Comment: I think the most easiest way is to get first letter and match for it.

Comment: What is the programming language?

Comment: What are you going to do after you match all the "a"s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you are trying to build would capture very first character then any thing up to the same character as much as possible, using a negative lookahead ([tempered dot](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed)):

```
(?i)(\w)(?:(?!\1).)*
```

Capturing group 1 holds the character you need. Try it on a [live demo](https://regex101.com/r/828Gk9/1).

If regex engine supports `\K` match re-setter token then you can append it to the regex above to [only match desired part](https://regex101.com/r/828Gk9/2/):

```
(?i)(\w)(?:(?!\1).)*\K
```

Comment: Wow! Great solution!